# Slicing a list with another list

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list that like:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to slice, selecting 'a', 'c', 'd'. I try doing:

```
list[0, 2, 3]
```

and I receive an error message that says: 'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'.

I also tried:

```
list[True, False, True, True, False]
```

and I receive an error message that says: 'list indices must be integers or slices, not list'.

Can anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: I don't believe this can be done as a slice, as the desired elements are irregular.  Did you really want a _slice_?

Comment: That is not a valid list slice ... Which is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result = [list[q] for q in selection]
```

where `selection` is the list with the indices you want to extract.

As a general rule: do not used `list` as variable name as it overrides the builtin `list()`

Answer (score 2):

```py
slicedList = [list[0],list[2],list[3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
li1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
selected = ['a', 'c', 'd']
list(filter(lambda x:x in selected, li1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

i = itemgetter(0, 2, 3)
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

print(i(lst))
```

Prints:

```
('a', 'c', 'd')
```